# chat app. for django

Tags: python, django, chat, django-views, livechat

Is there any facebook like chat application to integrate to django.If so please give an example and the source link

Thanks..

Answer (score 9):

Here are three:

- http://code.google.com/p/django-chat/ - demo works well, but code last updated in 2008, so possibly unmaintained
- http://code.google.com/p/django-jchat/ - uses jQuery. Maintained code with [good blog posts](http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/django-powered-ajax-chat-%E2%80%93-part-2/) explaining how it works
- http://code.google.com/p/django-jqchat/ - again, uses jQuery. Maintained code. Has demo that works well.

Answer (score 1):

maybe http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/chat/landscape/ ?